# Communication between Robotium test process and the App under test

Tags: android, ipc, robotium

I test an Android application using Robotium. But I want to provide some data to the application under test from my test process. In Android documentations, I read that Messenger can be used to communicate two Android processes. However, I have not come up with any use of Messenger in a ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 class.

Do you have any idea about how I can do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What data u want to provide.Can u explain what exactly you are facing problem?

Comment: I am testing an instrumented application in which I injected some additional classes. I want to provide parameters (e.g. integers) to that injected Thread class running in the original application, from the tester application that uses Robotium.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want to do this or what this test will achieve but the simplest way possible is to call a method on an activity that you have access to. Once you have an activity cast it to the activity type with the method and then you will now be able to call those methods. Should handle most cases like this.